# Trying to display column from subquery/array

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I am trying to display some columns in a datatable via my custom controller. The controller uses a SOQL query to retrieve the data. The query contains a subquery to recieve all rows in that subquery, this means the data is wrapped in a array.

I would like to know how I can display a column from the first item in the array, I've attempted to use `so.Status_History__r[0].Name`  to get the first item but this returns an error for the whole page.

**VF**

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!Orders}" id="orders-table" styleClass="table" var="so" width="100%">

                <apex:column headerClass="col-md-3 text-center" >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Status</apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!so.Status_History__r[0].Name}"/>
                </apex:column>
```

**Controller**

```
public list<Service_Order__c> getOrders(){
    lstItem = new list<Service_Order__c>();

    String query = 'SELECT Id, Name, CreatedDate, (SELECT Name FROM Status_History__r ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1) ';
    query += 'FROM Service_Order__c ';
    query += 'ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT :QueryLimit OFFSET :OffsetSize';

    lstItem = Database.query(query);
    return lstItem;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subquery may return more than one record. So, you will have iterate through the subquery records. For example

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!Orders}" id="orders-table" styleClass="table" var="so" width="100%">
                <apex:column headerClass="col-md-3 text-center" >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Status</apex:facet>
                    <apex:variable var="cnt" value="{!0}" /> 
                    <apex:repeat value="{!so.Status_History__r}"  var="history">
                          <apex:outputText value="{!history.Name}" rendered="{!cnt==0}"/>
                          <apex:variable var="cnt" value="{!cnt+1}"/>
                    </apex:repeat>
                    </apex:pageBlockTable>
                </apex:column>
```

This will iterate through all the subquery records and print them inside the column. As per your requirement, you can stop the apex:repeat iteration with another counter variable.

Comment: Could you explain further on your second point about how to display only the first value?

Comment: You could use apex:variable (counter) to display only the first value. I have updated the code.

Comment: in addition to using the counter method, because of the `LIMIT 1` on the subquery there will only ever be one item in the subquery list. No need to limit it in the VF markup too.

Comment: @MarkPond Good catch! I was aware of this, I put it in there to test if I could use this as a way to get only the first record.

Comment: There's also the *rows* attribute that can limit the display to a number of rows.

Comment: how would this work if the 'Status_History__r' relationship needs to be read from a String? As in, I am working on a generic method that receives the relationship name as input and needs to display the related records for each parent record. How would that work? I tried sobject.get[relationshipname] but the VF throws an error saying that it can't find that relationship.